# Is there any keyboard shortcut to switch (or choose) a given launch target?

Tags: visual-studio-code, build, target, launch

I have a Visual Studio Code project configured with multiple launch targets.

I'm aware I can select them on the `Run` dropdown in the `Run` view, however, I'd like to perform this operation via keyboard.

Is it possible? I can't find the action/keyboard shortcut in the keyboard shortcuts editor.

Comment: Look athttps://stackoverflow.com/a/61847595/836330 - it might be helpful.  You can set a shortcut to any specific launch config.

Comment: I updated the extension - now you can set multiple keybindings to different launch configurations.

Comment: @Mark interesting! if you convert it to answer, I'll upvote it - it will help people finding it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is no direct shortcut, it's possible to assign one to `Select and Start Debugging`, which yields essentially the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

See the extension [Launch A Config](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config).  You can make multiple keybindings to any of your launch configs.  Example keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",
  "command": "launches.RunNodeCurrentFile"
},
```

where in your settings.json you link that command to sone launch config `name`:

```
"launches": {
  "RunNodeCurrentFile": "Launch File",
  "Test": "Run Extension Tests",
  // and more 
},
```