# How can I always show the run & debug dropdown and run buttons in VS Code without switching to the run `Run and Debug` tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've created a `launch.json` file and can run and debug my app. However, to do that I have to click on "Run and Debug" on the left (or `ctrl+shift+D`). Then select the config from my `launch.json` and run it.

I'm looking for a way to have that drop down and run button always visible and usable without having to switch to the "Run and Debug" tab. Like in PyCharm:

[image: Pycharm]

I found https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/r42rps/tutorial_adding_run_and_debug_buttons_to_vscode/ that gets me sort of there but its very manual... All i want is for the current run debug dropdown that vscode already has to be usable at all times without sacrificing 1 3rd of my screen every time i want to run an app.

Comment: don't use the top-right triangle button, it does not use the launch config, select a launch config and then just press `F5` or `Shft+F5`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645098/vscode-keyboard-shortcut-for-launch-configuration/61847595#61847595.  While there is no way to show the built-in `Run and Debug` config dropdown without activating the Run and Debug view, you may find something helpful in the link, including making a keybinding to any launch config you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this without any extensions.

But you can get some other niceties in vanilla VS Code too.

- There's the `Debug: Select and Start Debugging` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), which, when invoked, prompts you to select a launch config from a keyboard-navigable menu to start debugging with. You can also bind it to a keyboard shortcut using it's command ID- `workbench.action.debug.selectandstart`.
- There's the `Debug: Start Debugging` command, which starts the currently selected launch config, and which you can bind to a keyboard shortcut using `workbench.action.debug.start`.
- There's also a `debug.startFromConfig`, where you can write a launch config in the `args` property (unfortunately, you'll have to have some "code duplication" (see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97921).

Comment: Happy to add an extension if needed but i haven't been able to find one