# How can I create a keybinding in VS Code that will run all default launch configurations inside of a workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

How to create such keybinding? When opening up a workspace, I want to easily run every service. For each service I have launch configuration configured.

Is it possible in vscode to create such keybinding that will go through all services, select the first launch configuration, and run them?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you're okay with duplicating your launch configs into your user-level keyboard shortcuts. Combine [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands) with `debug.startFromConfig`. If you want something better, you'll have to find or write an extension that does what you want. See also [vscode keyboard shortcut for launch configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48645098/11107541).